# Regexp in bash - edit lines

Tags: regex, bash, sed

I have several files which contains lines written in a particular way, for example like this :

```
>m.144 g.144  ORF g.144 m.144 type:internal len:123 (+) Pf1004_1/1_1.000_369:1-372(+)
```

I want to use sed commands with regexp to delete some characters in order to have this format :

```
>Pf1004_1/1_1.000_369
```

But it does not work :/. I used the following script :

```
 #/bin/bash

 for file in *.fasta # Set of fasta files in the script directory
 do      
     sed -i "s/.+?\(\+\) />/g" $file
     sed -i "s/:.+//g" $file
 done
```

What is wrong ? Here is an overview of one of my files :

```
>m.187 g.187  ORF g.187 m.187 type:internal len:115 (+) Ph1000_1/1_1.000_345:1-348(+)
LIILLTSVSVVVLLVENHLSPSHSVLDLSSEPPTGNATYHCWEVAETVIVIKECSPCSVF
EQKTNPACKETGYSQKVLCMLKDGTESKLPRSCPKITWVEEKQFWLFEVLMALLG
>m.188 g.188  ORF g.188 m.188 type:internal len:100 (+) Ph1002_1/1_1.000_302:1-303(+)
KTDTPRRQRSMSPVANVSCSPSVSSPNLLMKLLDSSDESESDTPHPNRVKVLKPDDMGIK
DFFKNTAAKQGLEERVDVSIQDFDHIINEASDRLPCTKKI
>m.189 g.189  ORF g.189 m.189 type:internal len:125 (+) Ph1007_1/1_1.000_376:1-378(+)
QSATPLHRAAEANRKQAVAELLHAGCDVNRQNEVSITPIFYPAQRGDDVTTRLLIQNGAD
PNVTDAEDWIPLHFASQNGHVATVDALTSARSMVNAAGSHGETPLLIAAEQGHDKVVKHL
LANGA
>m.190 g.190  ORF g.190 m.190 type:internal len:129 (+) Ph1010_1/1_1.000_387:1-390(+)
HVADTGTSSSPQLSPTHAERRPLKVEFIGMKDMASGDTSGRDKRPGVENDLKRINRKATN
CARYQQPRMSLLGKPLNYRAHKRDVRYRRAQAKVYNFLERPKDWRAISYHLLVYVELRDS
TLTVFHPSM
>m.191 g.191  ORF g.191 m.191 type:internal len:185 (+) Ph1014_1/1_1.000_555:1-558(+)
CLADLVTASDNMENDLSDNSNLDQSGTMYAFAAKRKSYGQVKDADHVDSGGDNPERQERP
MSPMCLKIRKSDNGLSPEARRPVTSPSPISPAAPVSDHVDADRDVIERAKELQKAELDKV
VASSFPVPQSGFRSVHSVDISPLHRISVPWPHPVHQPIFPHPHPVALQMSLSNSFRAQNP
DACIR
>m.192 g.192  ORF g.192 m.192 type:internal len:183 (+) Ph1025_1/1_1.000_551:1-552(+)
TQKDWRELLWTYCCCCSKRHVHAEDVDKSAVTSLSEVKAEKQLKSPAKIKTIRNHADVKS
ALSTSCLRRKKNFEEQTICKNELNVKHSDDDNRDMDKQDTKTAITLTPKCFVHFPKSVNH
LQLDQTPLYWGAVSKEAASLCSLPVRNGCTVAAVKDVQDPHLLEIGQVYQNDEEWTPKEL
TAD
>m.19 g.19  ORF g.19 m.19 type:internal len:348 (+) Ph103_1/1_1.000_1044:1-1047(+)
GGHLPSFNDRPGNTMAGSKDDKTNLSPVKLELISPCGPVLSNHVGCIVNNVLYIHGGINK
YLSKEPLNAFYKLNLNAPSPIWQEILDRNSPHLSHHACVVLDNRYLVLIGGWNGKQRTAD
MWAYDVQEAVWISLRTSGFPEGAGLSSHAALPLADGSILVIGREGSARIQRRYGNSWLIR
GSVMRGHFVYNEHQMSLASRSGHTMHVIGSDLTIIGGRSDRQVEQHGGYRTAMTSSAVAF
FSGLNQFVKRTPPMAKPPCGRKQHVSASGSGLILIHGGETFDGKSRHPVGDFYIISLRPT
VTWYHLGTSGVGRAGHVCCTAADKIIIHGGMGPRNAIYGDTYEISLSK
>m.193 g.193  ORF g.193 m.193 type:internal len:130 (+) Ph1046_1/1_1.000_390:1-393(+)
LFRLASESYHSSKMVQRLTLRRRLSYNTSSNRRRIVKTPGGRLVYHYTKKPGAIPICKSG
GCRTKLHGIRPSRPMQRRRMSKRLKTVNRTYGGVQCHTCVREKIIRAFLIEEQKIVVKVL
KAQAAQAKKA
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace your 2 ***sed***  expressions with the following one:

```
sed -E 's/^>.+\(\+\) ([^:]+):.+$/>\1/' $file
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not do something like:

```
sed -e 's/^.*[ ]([+])[ ]/>/g' -e 's/[:].*$//' $file
```

The first expression:

```
's/^.*[ ]([+])[ ]/>/g'
```

will remove from the beginning to the first `space` followed by `(+)space`.

The second expression:

```
's/[:].*$//'
```

just chops everything that remains from the `:` to the end.

**Example**

```
$ echo ">m.144 g.144  ORF g.144 m.144 type:internal len:123 (+) Pf1004_1/1_1.000_369:1-372(+)" | \
  sed -e 's/^.*[ ]([+])[ ]/>/g' -e 's/[:].*$//'
>Pf1004_1/1_1.000_369
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem may be that sed's regular expressions are not what you expect. See here for an explanation, expecially about what "+" represents: https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/html_node/Regular-Expressions.html

Answer (score 0):

Depending on how well structured your data is, this simple `awk` script could be enough:

```
awk -F '[ :]' '/^>/ { print ">" $12; next } 1' infile
```

Output:

```
>Ph1000_1/1_1.000_345
LIILLTSVSVVVLLVENHLSPSHSVLDLSSEPPTGNATYHCWEVAETVIVIKECSPCSVF
EQKTNPACKETGYSQKVLCMLKDGTESKLPRSCPKITWVEEKQFWLFEVLMALLG
>Ph1002_1/1_1.000_302
KTDTPRRQRSMSPVANVSCSPSVSSPNLLMKLLDSSDESESDTPHPNRVKVLKPDDMGIK
DFFKNTAAKQGLEERVDVSIQDFDHIINEASDRLPCTKKI
>Ph1007_1/1_1.000_376
QSATPLHRAAEANRKQAVAELLHAGCDVNRQNEVSITPIFYPAQRGDDVTTRLLIQNGAD
PNVTDAEDWIPLHFASQNGHVATVDALTSARSMVNAAGSHGETPLLIAAEQGHDKVVKHL
LANGA
>Ph1010_1/1_1.000_387
HVADTGTSSSPQLSPTHAERRPLKVEFIGMKDMASGDTSGRDKRPGVENDLKRINRKATN
CARYQQPRMSLLGKPLNYRAHKRDVRYRRAQAKVYNFLERPKDWRAISYHLLVYVELRDS
TLTVFHPSM
>Ph1014_1/1_1.000_555
CLADLVTASDNMENDLSDNSNLDQSGTMYAFAAKRKSYGQVKDADHVDSGGDNPERQERP
MSPMCLKIRKSDNGLSPEARRPVTSPSPISPAAPVSDHVDADRDVIERAKELQKAELDKV
VASSFPVPQSGFRSVHSVDISPLHRISVPWPHPVHQPIFPHPHPVALQMSLSNSFRAQNP
DACIR
>Ph1025_1/1_1.000_551
TQKDWRELLWTYCCCCSKRHVHAEDVDKSAVTSLSEVKAEKQLKSPAKIKTIRNHADVKS
ALSTSCLRRKKNFEEQTICKNELNVKHSDDDNRDMDKQDTKTAITLTPKCFVHFPKSVNH
LQLDQTPLYWGAVSKEAASLCSLPVRNGCTVAAVKDVQDPHLLEIGQVYQNDEEWTPKEL
TAD
>Ph103_1/1_1.000_1044
GGHLPSFNDRPGNTMAGSKDDKTNLSPVKLELISPCGPVLSNHVGCIVNNVLYIHGGINK
YLSKEPLNAFYKLNLNAPSPIWQEILDRNSPHLSHHACVVLDNRYLVLIGGWNGKQRTAD
MWAYDVQEAVWISLRTSGFPEGAGLSSHAALPLADGSILVIGREGSARIQRRYGNSWLIR
GSVMRGHFVYNEHQMSLASRSGHTMHVIGSDLTIIGGRSDRQVEQHGGYRTAMTSSAVAF
FSGLNQFVKRTPPMAKPPCGRKQHVSASGSGLILIHGGETFDGKSRHPVGDFYIISLRPT
VTWYHLGTSGVGRAGHVCCTAADKIIIHGGMGPRNAIYGDTYEISLSK
>Ph1046_1/1_1.000_390
LFRLASESYHSSKMVQRLTLRRRLSYNTSSNRRRIVKTPGGRLVYHYTKKPGAIPICKSG
GCRTKLHGIRPSRPMQRRRMSKRLKTVNRTYGGVQCHTCVREKIIRAFLIEEQKIVVKVL
KAQAAQAKKA
```